# colour for Status bar and action bar background does not change

Tags: android

I am currently implement toolbar into my code and having some issues with it. It does not display or change the colour of the status and bar background. Here is the code I wrote:

### toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

### styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>         
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>

    </style>

    <color name="blue">#3F51B5 </color> 

</resources>
```

### java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_warfarin_info);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]
May I know what did I do wrong? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in the toolbar layout XML file, you havent linked the style to the View. Try adding this line:

```
style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

ie:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    >
```

And the styles XML file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>

    </style>

    <color name="blue">#3F51B5 </color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Tried it but the same result.

Comment: Are you trying to set a static color as the back ground that doesnt change? or a color that changes based on some event?

Comment: @DanKCl  I made some changes to the code, try it now. It gives a static blue background to the Toolbar View.